# Percorrendo String html

Tags: android, html, webview

Boa tarde!

Estou recebendo um String html para exibir em um webview.

Dentro desse string pode ou não existir imagens, mas para mim exibí-la, 
tenho que passar uma URL base antes de src=\"crmResources/, exemplo: "http://desenv.ex.com.br/crmResources/..."

Então tenho que guardar toda a String até encontrar uma imagem, guardar em uma outra variável concatenando com uma variável URLBases (exemplo: http://desenv.ex.com.br/), ver se existem mais imagens para fazer o mesmo trabalho e no final concatenar tudo em uma String para exibir no webview.

Qual seria o melhor caminho ou lógica para fazer isso?
Lembrando que pode ou não existir imagens, e entre elas podem haver outros elementos html.

Comment: A string html que você recebe, é como se fosse a página inteira? Se sim, você poderia utilizar expressões regulares para fazer a substituição do src=\" pelo endereço da imagem

Comment: Isso, na verdade seria o conteúdo, parágrafos, subtítulos, imagens, listas e etc

Comment: Já tentou com replaceAll? variavelString.replaceAll("<img src=\"", "<img src=\"http://enderecodosite/");

Comment: Obrigado Alisson, funcionou legal, tive uns problemas com os \\, mas deu certo

Comment: Disponha, grato por ter ajudado. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a todo momento você estiver utilizando caminho **relativo**, como em seu exemplo, e tendo como base este endereço `http`, você pode utilizar o método  [`loadDataWithBaseURL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Fica assim mais ou menos:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://desenv.ex.com.br", strHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

Com isso, o seu `WebView` terá como base esta *URL*, e todo caminho relativo dentro desta *string* terá ela como referência.

Não há necessidade de percorrer todo o Html. Lembrando que você precisa ter permissão no seu *manifest* para acesso à internet.